# Issues with consecutive implementation of scanner.nextInt()

Tags: for-loop, input, integer, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to assign two variables, L and R, using scanner.nextInt().  After assignment, these variables are immediately used in a for-loop.  My issue is that the scanner stream remains open at the command line and the program never executes the succeeding for-loop.  Here's a snippet:

```
 System.out.println("Enter the Left and Right endpoints: ");
 L = sc.nextInt();
 R = sc.nextInt();

 for (int i = L; i < R; i += resolution) {
   double a = i, b = resolution+i;
     if (poly(C, a)*poly(C, b) < 0) {
      double mid = findRoot(C, a, b, tolerance);
      System.out.println(mid);
      if (Math.abs(poly(C, mid)) < threshold){
        System.out.println("Root found at: "+mid);
        numCount = 1;
      }
   } else if (poly(D, a)*poly(D, b) < 0) {
      double mid = findRoot(D, a, b, tolerance);
      if(Math.abs(poly(C, mid)) < threshold) {
        System.out.println("Root found at: "+mid);
        numCount = 2;

   } else {
     numCount = 3;
     System.out.println("No roots were found in the specified range.");
   }
   System.out.println("numCount is "+numCount); break;
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you know the loop isn't executed? What input do you pass in?

Comment: The loop will print a statement if it is executed.  At the UNIX command line, the stream remains open for integer input.  I have to use CTRL-C to quit the program execution.

Comment: Seems to work for me. Is there a specific input that creates this problem? Or perhaps your included snippet is over simplifying the problem?

Comment: I would guess that either your loop doesn't end, or you have another `nextSomething` call somewhere. What's `resolution`?

Comment: All input creates this problem.  In fact, it doesn't return an error when a non-integer is typed.

Comment: The variable resolution creates a limit for the width of the smaller intervals with which the root can be detected.

Comment: I believe the problem comes from the for-loop.  If I comment out the for-loop, L and R are properly assigned. I don't understand what is wrong with the loop.

Comment: Is `resolution` a double?

Comment: Yes, resolution is a double.

Comment: `i += resolution` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Then what is it doing?

Comment: Is resolution not the width of the subintervals [a,b] that form a partition of [L, R]?